# If $(^0E)^0=E$ for every closed subspace $E\subset X^*$ then $X$ is reflexive.

Tags: functional-analysis, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a normed vector space, $X^*$ be its dual and $X^{**}$ be its bidual.

For every $E \subset X^*$ we define the **left-annihilator** of $E$ as
$$^0E=\{x \in X : f(x)=0 \ \forall f \in E\}.$$
And for every $F \subset X$ we define the **annihilator** of $F$ as
$$F^0=\{f \in X^*: f(x)=0 \ \forall x \in F\}.$$
It is easy to see that $E \subset (^0E)^0$.

Suppose that for every closed subspace $E \subset X^*$ we have
$$E = (^0E)^0.$$

I want to prove that it implies $X$ is reflexive.

So, we want to show that the natural isometric linear injection $J_X:X \to X^{**}$, $J_X(x)(\varphi)=\varphi(x)$, is surjective.

That is, given $\Psi \in X^{**}$ there is $x \in X$ such that for every $\varphi \in X^*$ we have
$$\Psi(x)(\varphi)=\varphi(x).$$

These are some ideas I had but I didn't know how to use them:

Define $E:=null(\Psi) \subset X^*$. I think we should consider the case $E\neq X^*$ and then pick the $x\neq 0$ in
$$\bigcap_{f \in E}null(f),$$
that is, $x \in (^0E)$.

I also know that we have a natural isometric isomorphism $\Phi: X^*/E \to (^0E)^*$, $\Phi([f])=f|_{(^0E)}$.

I appreciate any ideas or comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should follow from the following facts:

- $(^0E)^0 = E$ if and only if $E$ is weak-$\star$ closed
- $\operatorname{null}(f)$ is closed if and only if $f$ is continuous
- $\operatorname{null}(f)$ is weak-$\star$ closed if and only if $f$ is weak-$\star$ continuous if and only if $f$ belongs to the image of $J_X$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain or give some reference to this first result?

Comment: This is sometimes known as the 'bipolar theorem' and often formulated in terms of topological vector spaces, see, e.g., Nonsmooth Analysis by Schirotzek, Prop. 2.3.3. It basically follows from the Hahn-Banach separation theorem (formulated in topological spaces).